# How do i get 3 numbers (100) to get displayed as 1,00?

Tags: android

Could someone explain to me how I can get 3 numbers, like 100, 200, 300 to a formatted view like 1,00 , 2,00 , 3,00 etc.

Comment: Have you ever heard of digits?

Comment: @greenapps when i set the inputtype to setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); , I can't click on the comma. that's why i wanted to try this. so if someone puts in 200 it goes to 2,00

Answer (score 0):

I will do this

```
int x = 200 ;
String.format("%d,%02d", x/100,x%100);
```

Answer (score 0):

May it can help you

```
Long result = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(value).replaceAll("\\,", ""));
```

value is the formatted number